# How can I join 2 tables by their dates in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables

cumulative_money_in:

```
Cumulative_amount | date
500               | Apr 12
570               | Apr 14
620               | Apr 16
```

cumulative_money_out:

```
Cumulative_amount | date 
100               | Apr 13 
170               | Apr 15 
200               | Apr 17
```

I want my result in this example to be:

```
Remaining_balance | date 
500               | Apr 12 
400               | Apr 13 
470               | Apr 14 
400               | Apr 15 
450               | Apr 16 
420               | Apr 17
```

i.e. I want to have a timeline of how the remaining balance (money_in-money_out) changes

What I have so far is this:

```
SELECT date, (COALESCE(money_in.cumulative_amount,0) - COALESCE(money_out.cumulative_amount,0)) 
FROM money_in 
FULL OUTER JOIN money_out 
ON money_in.date <= money_out.date
```

Which clearly is not what I want to have

Comment: You tagged your question MySQL, but the sample code uses `FULL JOIN`, which MySQL does not support.

Comment: convert the tables from cumulative to incremental values, and convert the out table to negatives. Then `UNION` the two tables and calculate running totals.

Answer (score 0):

You can `union all` your tables, `order by` date. and then calculate remaining money for each interval with a `left join`:

```
with money_start as (
   select *, 1 flag from money_in
   union all
   select *, -1 flag from money_out
),
money as (
  select * from money_start order by date
)
select case when m1.flag = 1 
            then m1.amount - coalesce(m2.amount, 0) 
            else m2.amount - m1.amount end remaining,
       m1.date
from money m1 
left join money m2 on m2.date = date_sub(m1.date, interval 1 day)
order by m1.date;
```

Output:

| remaining | date |
| --- | --- |
| 500 | 2021-04-12 |
| 400 | 2021-04-13 |
| 470 | 2021-04-14 |
| 400 | 2021-04-15 |
| 450 | 2021-04-16 |
| 420 | 2021-04-17 |